# In centos7 google-chrome can not run

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

os : centos7(docker)
chromedriver : 2.34.522913
google-chrome : Google Chrome 63.0.3239.108

Before I want to test with selenium, I installed chromedriver and google-chrome stable.

When I run google-chrome, I get this message.

Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Anyone help me?

Comment: don't run as root.

Comment: I also tried with not root.

Comment: and you still got "Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported"?

Comment: then I got this message.
`Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

Comment: Try updating to latest Chrome & Chromedriver to see if that fixes it. If that fails, add the --no-sandbox option to see if it runs without the sandbox. Not a real solution but might give you more information.